# using variable to match specific pattern within reg exp in perl

Tags: regex, perl, variables, pattern-matching

I would like to use a variable to match patterns with a regular expression.
The patterns I want to match are: `>crypt29_1` and `>crypt29_2`

```perl
my $var = crypt29

my $pattern = ">".$var."_"."*";
```

`$string =~ m/$pattern/;` matches to `>crypt29_1`, `>crypt29_2` as well as `>crypt290_2` and `>crypt2914_2`.

How can I make the match specific to match only `>crypt29_1` and `>crypt29_2`.

Answer (score 2):

`_*` means zero or more `_`. The solution is to simply remove the `*`. Then it will require a `_` following the `29`.

```perl
my $pattern = "^>\Q$var\E_";
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).